# Why is the site name in the schema markup but not showing in search results?

Tags: schema

Google doesn't appear the site name in the search results. https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWnFE.png

But the schema includes the name: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCTfH.png

I saw that there no guarantee to enhance your page’s SERP entry just because you use appropriate Schema.org, maybe the code isn't correct?
https://prnt.sc/Ccv6r9H-PJTW I have checked in the validator, there is ok, but there are a lot of properties to add the site name, maybe I need to add something?

The problem is for all pages, but this is for [page](https://porat.dev/%D7%90%D7%90%D7%95%D7%98%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%92/).

I want to chane the domain name to the site name in search results - https://prnt.sc/Ub15anQJQWRU